# Azure Application Gateway received invalid status code: 404 from App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

I am using Microsoft Learn to setup the following lab: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/load-balance-web-traffic-with-application-gateway/5-exercise-create-configure-application-gateway.

However, I can´t get it working as described as my app service always shows unhealthy due to:

> Received invalid status code: 404 in the backend server’s HTTP
> response. As per the health probe configuration, 200-399 is the
> acceptable status code. Either modify probe configuration or resolve
> backend issues. To learn more visit -
> https://aka.ms/StatusCodeMismatch.

I am wondering if this is a bug as the App Service is reachable http/https. I don´t know how the probe is made to path '/' but if it using http://app-service-default-name.azurewebservices.net/:80 that will fail. Could this be the reason or am I doing something wrong?

Best,
Mario

Comment: I figured out now by myself that the health probe is sent to (protocol)://(host name):(port from httpsetting)/urlPath so in my case. 
http://<default_site_hostname>.azurewebsites.net:80/. If I do that manually it works but the probe is still showing 404.

Answer (score 7):

Ok after various time of troubleshooting I was able to fix it myself by setting `Override with new host name` of the http settings to yes and then use `Pick host name from backend target`. Maybe that helps anyone else with that problem. For the CLI its the parameter `--host-name-from-backend-pool` I believe. Seems its missing in the exercise. But since I am using Terraform anyways I just had to update the `backend_http_settings` block with `pick_host_name_from_backend_address` and set the `probe_name`.